# How to print `Non-breaking space` to a pdf using apache pdf box?

Tags: java, pdfbox

```
final String NBSP = new String("\u00a0");
contentStream.showText("Konichua!" + NBSP);
```

this throws the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+00A0 ('nbspace') is not
>   available in this font Courier encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

I have tried it with all the 3 fonts available; TimesNewRoman, Courier & Helvitica with all 3 resulting in the same exception.

But when you look at the **WIN_ANSI_ENCODING_TABLE** present in the source code of apcahe pdfBox,

```
    {040, "space"},
    {0243, "sterling"},
     .
     .

    // adding some additional mappings as defined in Appendix D of the pdf spec
    {0240, "space"},
    {0255, "hyphen"}
```

we can see that the below *Non-breaking space* is defined.

```
DEC     OCT     HEX     BIN       Symbol     Description
```

```
160    240      A0      10100000              Non-breaking space
```

In the pdf specification [document](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)
the following is quoted too:

> The  SPACE  character  shall  also  be  encoded  as  312  in  MacRomanEncoding  and  as  240  in  WinAnsiEncoding
>   . This duplicate code shall signify a nonbreaking space; it shall be typographically the same as (U+003A) SPACE.

---

Use case:

To increase the width of header txt columns by adding padding with NBSP, so that it is not removed when `string.trim()` is called on header columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "it shall be typographically the same as (U+003A) SPACE".

So it doesn't have the nbsp / nbspace. Get your font by calling `PDType0Font.load(document, new File("..."))`.

Btw, calling `new String()` on a string is not a good idea.

Comment: > "Btw, calling new String() on a string is not a good idea."

I was just playing around with overloading the constructor of String by sending in different encoding types.

Comment: >  PDType0Font.load(document, new File("...")).

Thanks, now I understand. HELVITICA was the first font I used and it doesn't have support for npsapce according to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/fontsupport.htm, so, I assumed that the TimesNewRoman and Courier which is provided by pdfBox supports nbpace, again according to the link provided.