# Nbspace not available

Tags: pdfbox

I am using pdfbox 2.0.9

I have a [pdf with acrofrom only](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jFbsYGFOnx8EMiHgDsE8LQtfwJHSa5Gh) and I want set nbspace character to a field:

```
field.setValue("\u00A0");
```

But I get error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+00A0 ('nbspace') is not available in this font Courier encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
```

I understand font on current field is not supporting these character.

How can I with pdfbox2.0.14 get pdf fonts list available on my pdf?

This topic might be related [How to print `Non-breaking space` to a pdf using apache pdf box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944235/how-to-print-non-breaking-space-to-a-pdf-using-apache-pdf-box)

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is your code? Did you want to put nbspace into a field? The answer you linked to tells you how to use a font that has nbspace. And the current version is 2.0.14, not 2.0.9. Or do you want to change the font of a field? Then please write that in your question.

Comment: @mkl please apologize me! your response is ok for me, thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text fields in your PDF use the font **Helv**.

The **AcroForm** resources font **Helv** is defined with the following encoding:

```
5 0 obj
<<
  /Type/Encoding
  /Differences[
    24/breve/caron/circumflex/dotaccent/hungarumlaut/ogonek/ring/tilde
    39/quotesingle
    96/grave
   128/bullet/dagger/daggerdbl/ellipsis/emdash/endash/florin/fraction
      /guilsinglleft/guilsinglright/minus/perthousand/quotedblbase/quotedblleft
      /quotedblright/quoteleft/quoteright/quotesinglbase/trademark/fi/fl/Lslash
      /OE/Scaron/Ydieresis/Zcaron/dotlessi/lslash/oe/scaron/zcaron
   160/Euro
   164/currency
   166/brokenbar
   168/dieresis/copyright/ordfeminine
   172/logicalnot/.notdef/registered/macron/degree/plusminus/twosuperior
      /threesuperior/acute/mu
   183/periodcentered/cedilla/onesuperior/ordmasculine
   188/onequarter/onehalf/threequarters
   192/Agrave/Aacute/Acircumflex/Atilde/Adieresis/Aring/AE/Ccedilla
      /Egrave/Eacute/Ecircumflex/Edieresis/Igrave/Iacute/Icircumflex
      /Idieresis/Eth/Ntilde/Ograve/Oacute/Ocircumflex/Otilde/Odieresis
      /multiply/Oslash/Ugrave/Uacute/Ucircumflex/Udieresis/Yacute/Thorn
      /germandbls/agrave/aacute/acircumflex/atilde/adieresis/aring/ae
      /ccedilla/egrave/eacute/ecircumflex/edieresis/igrave/iacute
      /icircumflex/idieresis/eth/ntilde/ograve/oacute/ocircumflex/otilde
      /odieresis/divide/oslash/ugrave/uacute/ucircumflex/udieresis/yacute
      /thorn/ydieresis
  ]
>>
endobj
```

As there is no font program embedded for this font, this encoding is based on the **StandardEncoding**. This base encoding does not contain a non-breaking space. Furthermore your **Differences** array does not add **nbspace** either.

Thus, you cannot draw a non-breaking space using that encoding and, therefore, also not using that **Helv** font.

As far as I know, PDFBox does not supply replacement fonts in such a case, i.e. if asked to create a new text field appearance while setting a value which contains a character not supported in the form field default appearance font encoding.

---

One work-around might be to not ask PDFBox to generate an appearance to start with, instead mark the **AcroForm** with a **NeedAppearances** value **true**, and hope a later PDF processor / viewer does use a replacement font in such a case. There is no guarantee this works, probably the next processor needing appearances also doesn't supply replacement fonts. Nonetheless, there at least is a chance it does...

Depending on the exact version of PDFBox, though,

```java
field.setValue(value);
```

may always trigger appearance generation. If that is the case for you, you have to set the field value like this

```java
field.getCOSObject().setString(COSName.V, value);
```

Comment: in 2.0 `setValue()` does not generate an appearance if `NeedAppearances` is `true`. (in the trunk it always does)

Comment: @Tilman Ah, ok. I'm currently working with trunk only... ;) - Ok, adapted the answer accordingly. (Does trunk do so for PDF 2.0 compatibility?)